# how to set jenkins changeset exclude setting

Tags: jenkins, changeset

I'd like to know if there is something opposite to changeset in Jenkins. 
For example, in the doc (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), an example is given for changeset setting:

```
when { changeset pattern: ".TEST\\.java", comparator: "REGEXP" } or when { changeset pattern: "*/*TEST.java", caseSensitive: true }
```

I'd like to know if I can set "changeset exclude" patterns so that the files match this pattern will not trigger certain stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex pattern to create a changeset filter that excludes certain paths, for example:

```
when {
  changeset pattern: '^(?!.*\.TEST\.java).*', comparator: "REGEXP"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it by myself, but surrounding the condition with `not{}` should do the trick:

```
when {
  not {
    changeset pattern: "*/*TEST.java", caseSensitive: true
  }
}
```

See [Pipeline Syntax (when)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) (scroll down to `not`).

Comment: There is a problem doing it this way: If I have made multiple changes, both in the changeset and not in the changeset, then the stages will not execute(changeset become TRUE, not{} makes it FALSE, so the when condition will not meet). Any solution to work around it?

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you trying to archive, but you can combine multiple conditions with `anyOf {}` and `allOf {} `.